# Which Build Process Template?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

in TFS Build 2013 how do you decide which Build Process Template to use?

I see 7 in the menu but no information on what to use.

I'm building through .proj msbuild file which calls custom tasks and does alot of copying a checking out. Building 6 solutions. Code is in VSO.

I've tried 3 and found:

- DefaultTemplate.11.1 works sort of, cannot compile websites.
- UpgradeTemplate does not compile for me.
- TfvcTemplate.12 does not compile for me.

Comment: Which version control are you using - TFVC or Git?

Comment: TFVC..................

Comment: I am wondering about the same question